# What's "NY-CONWEB02"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I saw this at the very bottom of the [Winter Bash 2022](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) source code and it stuck out to me:

```html
<!-- NY-CONWEB02 -->
```

Don't you think the people deserve to know what this means?

Comment: Code for secret hat, duh. :D

Answer (score 14):

Its a hostname.

Looking at one of the [old blog posts](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/), and the previous edition, its *almost* consistent with the hostnames "NY-WEBxx" used there.

SE's primary tier is in NY, so it indicates the datacenter and its the 3rd web server of its type. con *might* be a reference to being a container - I'm guessing here *but* spinning up a container for a 'temporary' event makes sense. I don't know if SE does Azure (or what the prefix for that is) or windows containers for any public Q&A production but it makes a lot of sense.

Considering winterbash is a relatively 'small' thing, I'd guess that its on a single server/container for easier troubleshooting, or its a server for things like this, and leaving it as a comment makes it easier for folks to figure out what to poke at looking at the code or webpage. Its an event lasting less than a month and its almost hardly long enough to save things to human non volatile memory.

Of course I could be completely wrong. I'm guessing quite a lot of the details :D

Comment: I suspected that, but how do I use this information to get more hats???

Comment: That's the real question innit :D

Comment: I just realised *in theory* enough upvotes on this and I might get a hat. >_> Which might answer your question :D

Comment: Note that while it says NY, it isn't actually New York.

Comment: It's New Jersey - I am aware